# ASP.NET MVC Get the ID of Inserted Item by stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am using Store Procedure to insert in the table `FASEC`. I want get the last id inserted after call Store Procedure.

How Can I get the last id inserted after calling Store procedure?

fasec.IDFASEC always 0

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateFASEC([Bind(Prefix = "Item1")] FASEC fasec)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ObjectParameter p_Result = new ObjectParameter("p_Result", typeof(Int32));

            db.SPINSFASEC(fasec.FECHAFASEC, fasec.DIAGNOSTICOFINAL, fasec.VIGENTE, fasec.IDCIE10,
                fasec.IDPRESTADOR, fasec.HISTORIALMEDICO, fasec.FECHAINICIO, fasec.FECHATERMINO,
                fasec.FECHARENOVACION, fasec.IDBENEFICIARIO, fasec.IDTIPOEVALUACION, fasec.IDESTADOFASEC,
                fasec.RESOLUCION, fasec.OBSERVACION, fasec.RUTAUTORIZO, fasec.IDEMPRESA, p_Result);

            if (p_Result.Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { mostrarError = 1});
            }
            else
            {                    
                db.SaveChanges();

                var lastId = fasec.IDFASEC;

            }                
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE spInsFasec
   (p_FechaFasec        IN FASEC.FECHAFASEC%TYPE,
    p_DiagnosticoFinal  IN FASEC.DIAGNOSTICOFINAL%TYPE,
    p_Vigente           IN FASEC.VIGENTE%TYPE,
    p_IdCie10           IN FASEC.IDCIE10%TYPE,
    p_IdPrestador       IN FASEC.IDPRESTADOR%TYPE,
    p_HistorialMedico   IN FASEC.HISTORIALMEDICO%TYPE,
    p_FechaInicio       IN FASEC.FECHAINICIO%TYPE,
    p_FechaTermino      IN FASEC.FECHATERMINO%TYPE,
    p_FechaRenovacion   IN FASEC.FECHARENOVACION%TYPE,
    p_IdBeneficiario    IN FASEC.IDBENEFICIARIO%TYPE,
    p_IdTipoEvaluacion  IN FASEC.IDTIPOEVALUACION%TYPE,
    p_IdEstadoFasec     IN FASEC.IDESTADOFASEC%TYPE,
    p_Resolucion        IN FASEC.RESOLUCION%TYPE,
    p_Observacion       IN FASEC.OBSERVACION%TYPE,
    p_RutAutorizo       IN FASEC.RUTAUTORIZO%TYPE,
    p_IdEmpresa         IN FASEC.IDEMPRESA%TYPE,
    p_result            OUT NUMBER) IS

  cCeroValor  CONSTANT NUMBER := 0;
  cUnoValor CONSTANT NUMBER := 1;  
  vCont NUMBER(10);
  vIDFASEC  NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO vCont 
      FROM COBERTURA 
      WHERE ACTIVO = cUnoValor AND
            IDEMPRESA = p_IdEmpresa;

IF vCont > 0 THEN

  INSERT INTO FASEC( 
    FECHAFASEC, 
      DIAGNOSTICOFINAL, 
      VIGENTE, 
      IDCIE10, 
      IDPRESTADOR, 
      HISTORIALMEDICO, 
      FECHAINICIO, 
      FECHATERMINO, 
      FECHARENOVACION, 
      IDBENEFICIARIO, 
      IDTIPOEVALUACION, 
      IDESTADOFASEC, 
      RESOLUCION, 
      OBSERVACION, 
      RUTAUTORIZO,
      IDEMPRESA)
    VALUES
     (p_FechaFasec,
      p_DiagnosticoFinal,
      p_Vigente,
      p_IdCie10,
      p_IdPrestador,
      p_HistorialMedico,
      p_FechaInicio,
      p_FechaTermino,
      p_FechaRenovacion,
      p_IdBeneficiario,
      p_IdTipoEvaluacion,
      p_IdEstadoFasec,
      p_Resolucion,
      p_Observacion,
      p_RutAutorizo,
      p_IdEmpresa)
      RETURNING IDFASEC INTO vIDFASEC;    

  INSERT INTO COBERTURAFASEC
                    (IDCOBERTURAFASEC, 
                    IDFASEC, 
                    IDCOBERTURA, 
                    PORCENTAJEREEMBOSO)
                    SELECT  SEQ_COBERTURAFASEC.NEXTVAL,
                            vIDFASEC, 
                            IDCOBERTURA, 
                            PORCENTAJEREEMBOSO 
                      FROM COBERTURA
                    WHERE ACTIVO = cUnoValor AND
                          IDEMPRESA = p_IdEmpresa;   

p_result := 1;  

END IF;  

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get inserted value from stored procedure using output

```
INSERT INTO FASEC( 
FECHAFASEC, 
  DIAGNOSTICOFINAL, 
  VIGENTE,
 )
output inserted.FECHAFASEC //inserted.coloumn Name
  VALUES(
     )
```